# How do I Create a JavaScript API That I Can Call From Python?

Tags: javascript, java, python, node.js, api

I wrote a program (more of a website currently) in JavaScript using Node.js. You can find it here: https://github.com/bhofff/Wikipedia-Image-Data-Tool

I'm a little confused on a couple things pertaining to JavaScript and also would like to know how to run a function containing a JavaScript API from a python file.

### First some background.

The purpose of the program is to use the Wikipedia API to download all the images on a specific page, their respective descriptions and then the main body page. It creates a new file for each page on my desktop, named after the page, and all the files go in there.

As of now the Wiki.js file that handles getting all the data from Wikipedia is run on a server from and index.ejs (which is like and html). Node runs the app.js which starts the server. You go to http://localhost:3000/wiki and type in the name of the Wikipedia page you want and it sends that to Wiki.js which collects image URLs and text strings and sends them to wikiController.js which is not hosted on the server and handles creating the folder with the page name and downloading the image and text files to it.

### My Questions.

1. My First question is whether the Wiki.js has to be hosted on a server. I believe it does but just curious.
2. Assuming it does and I host it on a server what do I need so that a python script can call it from my computer (sending the page name) and receive the data back? Basically I want to wrap Wiki.js in an API that can be called by a python script.
3. Next I want to not use Node.js for downloading anything. This question is the most confusing for me because, even though I wrote all the code for wikiController.js, I don't actually know where it operates, on the client or the server? My understanding is that:

   I) Node runs app.js,

   II) Then inside app.js I do:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var wikiController = require('./controllers/WikiController');
    var app = express();
    wikiController(app);
```

which runs wikiController.js and send some kind of var/object (app) so that it can be used in wikiController.js??

III) Then we start hosting the server:

```
    app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('we be listening to da port of 3000');
    });
```

But "wikiController(app);" happens first, so is wikiController.js just editing the "app" object/whatever-it-is so that on the next line when the server starts it knows what the html(ejs) for the pare is and what to do for all the requests?

This ties back to my first question because I thought "Java creates applications that run in a virtual machine or browser while JavaScript code is run on a browser only." Is node what is allowing me to run the JavaScript on my computer? I am very confused.

4. An API will work if I host it on GitHub right? feels like a stupid question but I just want to be sure.
5. can I use a .py or a .java to run app.js and localhost the server (assuming I already re codded app.js to not use Node)?

```
    //example 1
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wiki/' + 'descriptions',
        data: tempDes,
        success: function(sendData) {
        }
    });
    //example 2
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wiki/' + foldername,
        data: foldername,
        success: function(folderData) {
        }
    });
```

### How I want it to work.

1) I host the server probably from GitHub.

2) thing1.py calls thing2(python or java or JavaScript I don't care) and sends two strings to thing2 ('Title of page', 'File directory location').

3) thing2 send the 'Title of page' to the server/API on GitHub

4) GitHub server which will do everything it already does in Wiki.js but instead of the second POST request it does in each function (e.g. lines 145-151, 159-166 *also shown above*) it sends the data (images and text strings), in the "success:" field of the API, back to thing2 which downloads it.

Thank you so much for any help in advance!

Comment: Your API should be hosted on a server that is always running you cannot host it on Github (Github just hosts the code). From there, you will be able to make calls to the API from any other machine, including the same one. The node.js app is the server in this case.

Next you can create a client app/script to interact with the server. First you need to create an express route that allows your API to send the data you would like to send to the client. Next you If you want to use python to make the calls look into this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-requests/

Comment: My recommendation is to do the following:
1. Create a node api server that handles all interactions with wikipedia
2. Create a client application in python that interacts with the node server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's take this bit by bit, roughly in the order that you asked, but deviating in some places.

There are quite a few issues here. The first and most important of these is that you don't really understand what Node.js is or what it does. As you suggested, Node.js is a server-side implementation of JavaScript-- in other words, it allows you to run JavaScript on a server, completely separate from your web browser (in this case, the server is `localhost`). I would really recommend going back to learn the basics about the framework you're using before attempting to implement something like this.

If `Wiki.js` is interacting with your Node.js server, yes, you'll want that on the server. Since I don't know the details of what `Wiki.js` contains, it's hard to be more specific than that. Again, going back to the basics of Node.js would probably be helpful here.

`wikiController` runs on your server, as evidenced by the fact that you're calling it in `app.js`, which *is* your server. Calling `wikiController(app);` does "edit" the `app` object, presumably extending its functionality once you start listening for connections.

GitHub isn't a server host. GitHub pages are static HTML, so you can't run an API on them. I would recommend you take a look at [Glitch](https://glitch.com/), which will allow you to host a Node.js server to test your API. It's free with some limitations, but they probably won't affect you while you're testing. It also integrates with GitHub so you can commit your changes to your GitHub repository and have them automatically updated on your web server.

In order to "use a .py or a .java to run app.js", you would need to make a web request in either Python or Java directed at `localhost` if you're running your Node.js app locally, or at your public web URL should you choose to host it on the web.

As I see it , most of the issues you're experiencing here are due to a lack of foundational knowledge of Node.js, JavaScript, and APIs in general. This isn't a bad thing, but I'd recommend looking for an in-depth course or guide on creating a simple server, then going from there.

Comment: Could I possibly connect to Wikipedia API from a python or java file not hosted on a server? Like one that is just on my desktop? Also, thank you so much, for your help!

Comment: @BrandonHoffmann By the looks of it, yes! A quick search on PyPI turns up an old but popular open-source package called [`wikipedia`](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) that allows you to interact with Wikipedia's APIs natively in Python. The description specifically mentions retrieving all the images from an article.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero!

Comment: @BrandonHoffmann No problem! Glad I could help. If you're satisfied with my answer and believe it solved your issue, please [vote it up and click the check mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to close your question.